# pg_cron: Can I see how many scheduled cron jobs are awaiting an available worker?

Tags: postgresql, cron

I'm using `pg_cron` to schedule numerous concurrent, long-running (1 to 3+ hrs) jobs on a database. On this database there are only 5 background workers allocated to run cron jobs, so I've set up a staggered schedule that should result in only a few jobs actively running at any given time.

However, jobs may sometimes run longer than planned. If all the workers are busy when a new job is scheduled, then that new job does not run until a worker is freed up. I know that the `cron.job_run_details` table can tell me what jobs are running, but is there an easy way to find out if there's jobs that *aren't* running (yet)?

How can I find out how many cron jobs are queued up waiting for an available worker?

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look into pgAgent. There you can easily query jobs and their steps' statuses with easy SQL queries. Cheers

Comment: Thanks Jim, but this is taking place on RDS which doesn't support pgAgent as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hey Suzanne have you figured out how to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.